# Solving homogeneous Inequalities

Tags: inequality

I came to know from a book that if we have a homogeneous Inequality, that is every term in the Inequality has same degree, then we can scale the variables by some specific factors and after the "scailing" if the new inequality is true, the we can say that the original inequality was also true. Now my doubt is that why does it only work for homogeneous Inequalities and not non homogeneous Inequalities. Thank you

Comment: That is the definition of a homogeneous inequality, instead of some property of it.

Comment: if homogeneity is not satisfied, then one cannot scale the inequality.

Comment: @TobyMak isn't the definition of homogeneous inequality is that all the terms has to be of the same degree?

Comment: @asymptotic that's exactly what I am asking for. What is the reason of that?

Comment: Well the lhs and rhs of the inequality would not have the same degree in the scaling parameter, $\lambda$, say

Comment: Indeed, your definition is equivalent to this one. If we replace $x, y, z$ by $\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z$, then $(\lambda x)(\lambda y)(\lambda z) = \lambda^3 xyz$, where $xyz$ has degree $3$, matching the exponent of $\lambda^3$.

Comment: It is not necessary for all of the terms to have the same degree: this works too with $xy^2z^3$.

Comment: Umm can you please clarify how do we define homogeneous inequality at the first place. To the best of my knowledge it is the inequality where every term has the same degree, and the fact that we can scale homogeneous Inequalities by some factor and it would still be true is a property of homogeneous Inequality. I'm asking for the reason how it would be true, and why it won't be true otherwise (non-homogenous Inequality)

Comment: The definition is given in Brilliant: https://brilliant.org/wiki/homogeneity-in-solving-inequalities/.

Comment: It might also be useful to check out Evan Chen's handout, specifically section 1.2 (https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Ineq/en.pdf).

Comment: @TobyMak if I'm not mistaken, the word homogeneous is used where the terms in an expression have the same degree? Also if the definition given in brilliant is considered, then can I say if I can multiply variables of an Inequality by some factor while the preserving the validity of the Inequality, then i can say that the terms in the Inequality have same degree, that is the Inequality is homogeneous. https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Homogeneous